# Can you use both styles and styleUrls in an Angular component?

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 component, I'm using `styleUrls` to import a common stylesheet, but dont want to create a whole new stylesheet for a single rule that I want to add specific to this component.

Can I also define `styles`? So in my component I'm declaring both `styles` and `styleUrls` but it doesn't appear to work.

Just wanted to verify if this is possible or not.

Comment: @Vega i think he meant a specific component. using both styles and styleUrls

Comment: Thank you, NuttLoose. I understood that already. That is not possible as far as I know and I think the OP made the test for that. I was wondering what he has in the common stylesheet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible to use both `style` and `styleUrls` together. The [doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#loading-component-styles) says,

> There are several ways to add styles to a component:
>
> - By setting `styles` **or** `styleUrls` metadata.

But, for your problem, I found something helpful in [doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-urls-in-metadata):

> If you use module bundlers like Webpack, you can also use the styles
>   attribute to load styles from external files at build time. You could
>   write:
>
> `styles: [require('my.component.css')]`
>
> Set the styles property, not the styleUrls property. The module
>   bundler loads the CSS strings, not Angular. Angular sees the CSS
>   strings only after the bundler loads them. To Angular, it's as if you
>   wrote the styles array by hand. For information on loading CSS in this
>   manner, refer to the module bundler's documentation.

This way you can add both your common stylesheet and the single rule. For example:

```
styles: [require('his-common.component.css'), 'h1 { font-weight: normal; }']
```

Comment: I read multiple times your answer and I still not get how we can import two stylesheets or one inline and one file or ...     styles:[require('my.component.css')]  is for  build time and what is the difference with the usual declaration for the OP's case.

Comment: It's not a solution, I provided some helpful information from the doc that OP might find useful. For example, he can do `styles: [require('his-common-stylesheet.component.css'), 'h1 { font-weight: normal; }']` to include both his stylesheet and the rule. Please elaborate on what you mean by "difference with usual declaration for the OP's case"? if you are talking about his `styleUrls` use, then the problem is, he has to make another stylesheet for his single rule, which he doesn't want to. That's why I provided the info that I did.

Comment: ah! styles: [require('his-common.component.css'), 'h1 { font-weight: normal; }'] is a good one. I didn't know. Put it in your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This helped fix a bug in IE11 when defining both :}

Answer (score 5):

As it was said before, it's not possible to combine style and stylesheet.

If you don't want to mix up your stylesheets, you have some possibilities (from my head what comes first) :

1. Put the specific styles (as few as they are) in an other style sheet and do

   styleUrls:["stylesheet1","stylesheet2"]
2. Use  require('style-loader!./../../assets/stylesheet.css') to load external stylesheet via the class component for the specific style as you need and when you need.
3. Move the common element styles to styles.css next to index.html and "free" styleURLs or style: for the specific styles.

There are maybe some other solutions but those should be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Although this was not supported on earlier versions, starting from Angular 9 it is possible:

> You can specify more than one styles file or even a combination of
>   styles and styleUrls.

Here's a link to the latest [doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-files-in-component-metadata) (if you look at older versions docs that remark is omitted).